# Off-site HA server

Tags: centos, high-availability

I understand that this is a little too broad question, but I hope I can get some guidelines here.

I have a CentOS 5 server with cPanel on it. It is extremely important not to have downtime, but lately our provider have a lot of networking issues. Given that hardware or network problems can cause server downtime, I thought to set up mirrored server in some other data center. Now here is problem. I understand concept of HA.  I worked with clustered servers, but within same data center. I plan to use DRBD to mirror files and MySQL replication to keep database up to date, but I don't know how to connect servers on two separate locations.

They can't share same virtual IP address, or at least I don't know if that is possible, especially because there are two different providers. It those two servers (master and slave) have different IP addresses, how slave server can took over master role if master server is down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to have a low TTL on your DNS entry for the server and a programmatic mechanism for updating it.  In the event of a failover, you would bring up any necessary services on your failover server and modify the appropriate DNS entry to point to the address of the new server.

Many DNS provides (Amazon Route 53, Zerigo, others) provide the necessary API to make this sort of thing work.

Note also that DRBD can be problematic (i.e., cause noticeable latency in writes) over a WAN link (which is why LinBit offers the [DRBD proxy](http://www.drbd.org/users-guide/s-drbd-proxy.html) product).

It is actually possible to make the same ip address available from two different physical locations, although there's a lot more involved than DNS-based solutions; see [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/355201/ip-level-failover-for-web-servers-with-bgp-am-i-insane) on ServerFault for some pointers and discussion.

Comment: So I would just set two servers with DRBD/DRBD proxy, MySQL replication/whatever and Amazon Route 53 would do DNS Failover Health Checks and point to slave server if necessary? I would also have to set slave to check master and start services, set MySQL to master mode etc. as would I do in any other HA setup... Did I understood that right?

Comment: Mostly, yes.  I was not actually suggesting that Route 53 would do the health checks and failover for you...thought it might.  I haven't used that service.  I *was* suggesting that it gives you the necessary API to perform those services yourself.